# Genymotion virtual device stop working when i launch VPN app

Tags: vpn, genymotion

I've installed VPN app on my genymotion device but when i launch the VPN app, the device blocked & stop working!
I've tried a few apps (nordvpn + expressvpn) + Free apps but the same problem when launch it it stops working.
Also, I've tried other virtual devices ... also the same problem!
I've changed the network mode to Bridge .. guess what? the same problem Haha
I record the problem so you can see this https://youtu.be/WidljanG5jk

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the VPN redirects the Host-only interface which Genymotion uses to communicate with VirtualBox. You need to change your VPN settings as explained at https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002718258-Genymotion-Desktop-and-VPN .